# Unix: Perform grep command for every line from inputfile and save output to file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a small unix script to search one file for the line that contain a certain term, found in a different file. I would like to save the output of this command to a new file.

I have a file containing terms (terms.txt) which has a term on each line:

```
term1
term2
term3
term4
```

For each of these terms, I want to find the line that contains this term in another file (scores.txt) and append the output of this to a new file (output.txt).

The script I have come up with thus far:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `cat terms.txt`;
do 
grep -i $f scores.txt >> output.txt;
done
```

Somehow this does not seem to work properly. 
Running just the grep command with the term hard coded does indeed give me the right line I'm searching for:

```
grep -i "term1" scores.txt
```

Also, a simple echo does give me the right terms:

```
for f in `cat terms.txt`; do echo $f; done
```

However, when I try to repeat this with the $f variable, to repeat the same command for every term in my terms.txt, it does not work.

Could someone help me out on this one?

Comment: Look in the grep man page for the `-f` option. You do not need a loop at all.

Comment: @Bouke: Check out answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try:

```
grep -if terms.txt scores.txt > output.txt
```

basically `grep`'s option `f` treats the strings in the `terms.txt` file as patterns to search for in `scores.txt`

If your `terms.txt` has CRLF line endings, try this:

```
grep -if <(tr -d '\r' < terms.txt) scores.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've tried, but it is also not giving me any output. Even a simple "grep -if terms.txt scores.txt" does not give me any output.

Comment: Edit: Maybe the layout of my terms.txt and scores.txt messes up things a bit?
Just a quick paste so you better understand what I'm trying to do:
terms.txt: http://pastebin.com/yxJL1cQE, 
scores.txt: http://pastebin.com/bw46Utpk

Basicly, I'm trying to find the sentiment score found in scores.txt for every ANP that is in terms.txt

Comment: What does `file terms.txt` return? Does it say anything about `CRLF line terminators` ?

Comment: testANPs.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators. Encoding problem? I'm sorry, im just really not that experienced with Unix

Comment: Try running `dos2unix terms.txt` If `dos2unix` is not available on your distro, try one of the options from [here](http://superuser.com/questions/52044/convert-crlfs-to-line-feeds-on-linux)...

Comment: @Bouke: That is why `read -r` is for in my answer above. With that any unescaped backslashes in the input will be discarded and  by default it removes all leading and trailing whitespace characters (spaces and tabs, if present in IFS)

Comment: @anishsane nifty trick :) will keep for future references.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! The "grep -if <(tr -d '\r' < terms.txt) scores.txt > output.txt" did the trick for me! 
I should stop mixing Windows and Unix platforms..

Comment: I cheered a bit too early. Although this command worked, and I've found all the sentiment scores for the ANP's I need... It messed up the sequence in which the ANP's were found in the original terms.txt.

How can I make my output.txt have the scores on the same line as which the ANP was found in terms.txt?

Comment: @atanation, here are more details about what I did with `<(...)` syntax: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution